# Deterministic random number generator tied to instance (thread independent)

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, generator

Random numbers have been well covered here, so I'll keep it brief.

I use `srand` and `rand` to generate some deterministic random numbers in a simulation. However, when running multiple simulations at once on separate threads, the individual sequence gets muddled up and becomes non deterministic, because all threads draw from the same pool. Is there an easy way to "bind" `rand` to draw from a specific instance? Or would I have to switch to something like `Boost.Random`?

Comment: If your `srand` and `rand` share global state, how do you even know that they are thread-safe?

Comment: That is actually a very good point David. 0_o

Comment: Actually, quick follow on question. I have now used the random headers from boost, but even though I use a seed value I get different random numbers for different compilation options (debug vs release etc). Is this to be expected?

Comment: Follow on questions should appear as new questions.

Comment: no, that sounds strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler most likely already has something very like Boost.Random.

C++0x includes a `<random>` header which is based on Boost.Random (with a few tweaks here and there).

Before then, TR1, a set of "semi-standard" libraries was available for most compilers as well, which contains nearly the same `<random>` header.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, `rand_r` is a reentrant version of `rand`, but it is a rather weak PRNG, so might want to use something from the `*rand48_r` family of functions.

`rand_s` is a reentrant version of `rand` on Windows, but since its state is an unsigned int, it is also bound to be quite weak.

Long story short, you're probably better off with Boost.Random.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend using `<random>` or `<tr1/random>` for fine-grained access to high-quality PRNG classes which you can instantiate one in each thread with full control over their seeds and thus their resulting sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code, keeping a `rnd_state` struct for each of the threads. You may initialize the rnd_state with `rand()`. It's just an idea and this is a reasonable RNG.

From the linux kernel source code (random32.c)

the values in rnd_state should be initialized like: s1 > 1, s2 > 7, s3 > 15.

The paper claims this is a maximally equidistributed combined Tausworthe generator
based on code from GNU Scientific Library 1.5 (30 Jun 2004)

```
struct rnd_state {
    u32 s1, s2, s3;
};

static u32 __random32(struct rnd_state *state)
{
#define TAUSWORTHE(s,a,b,c,d) ((s&c)<<d) ^ (((s <<a) ^ s)>>b)

    state->s1 = TAUSWORTHE(state->s1, 13, 19, 4294967294UL, 12);
    state->s2 = TAUSWORTHE(state->s2, 2, 25, 4294967288UL, 4);
    state->s3 = TAUSWORTHE(state->s3, 3, 11, 4294967280UL, 17);

    return (state->s1 ^ state->s2 ^ state->s3);
}
```

Academia: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/tausme.ps

Comment: Just for reference, 32-bit 4 component and 64-bit 5 component Tausworthe generators (described in [this](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/tausme2.ps) paper) can be found at http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/rng/ (`lfsr113.c` and `lfsr258.c` respectively). They appear to be an improvement on the 3 component generator in your answer.

Comment: By the way, do you know of any tests for correctness of the Tausworthe you list (i.e. the million-th value should be xxx)?

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of PRNGs are being added to the standard library.  Another option is to pregenerate a large pool of numbers for each thread and then issue them one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for my C++ random number library, RandomLib, contains
an illustration of using parallel number streams in OpenMP; see
http://randomlib.sourceforge.net/html/parallel.html.  You might be
able to adapt the ideas presented there to your application.